# shortcut file path

Tags: c#

C# does anybody know how to make a shortcut declared path of a file.

```
picturebox.imagelocation = @"C:\ApplicationFolder\picture.jpg";
```

now what if the user will install the application in a different drive it will cause an error
so does anyone knows how to make a short path and ignoring the drives in making the path declaration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [relative paths](http://support.dtsearch.com/webhelp/dtsearch/relative_paths.htm) strating from your application's folder. should you then need the absolut path you can still use the [Path.GetFullPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfullpath.aspx) Method

Comment: hmmm..ive done that...but its not what im looking for... 

here is the situation...when i select a picture for the picturebox it retrieve the pictures full path...and now the next step is to copy the picture to a different path.Which i use a full path declaration like D:\newfolderapplication\picture.jpg

next problem what if the user installed the application in a different path which ive declared.

Comment: ive solve it by the way..thank.. it would be...    @..\..\folder\newfile.jpg